# kernel panic after addition of the "file" utility, resulting in bulky rootfs.cpio

Tags: kernel, buildroot, rootfs, initramfs

I am using an Initramfs for a custom chip, currently on an FPGA platform. Before generating the linux image using make, I ran make menuconfig and added the 'file' utility. It increased the rootfs.cpio size by 3 times, while the vmlinux size was *relatively* same. After booting I got following message:

> *----- entering function in file init/initramfs.c, line 463 Compressed data magic: 0x1f 0x8b Detected gzip compressed data
> ------ entering function in file init/initramfs.c, line 468 swapper invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x200d2, order=0, oom_score_adj=0  [ pid
> ] uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
> Kernel panic - not syncing: Out of memory and no killable
> processes...*

There is a custom tool for converting this vmlinux into another binary file which can be loaded in the FPGA's flash.

So where should I be making the corrections?In buildroot settings or in the scripts for generating the fpga flash's binary?